# Excel 2016 VBA failed calling vs2015 c++ dll

Tags: excel, visual-c++, dll, 64-bit, vba

Recently upgraded to a new PC with Win 10 pro, Excel 2016 coming with Office365, vs2015 community. Built a very simple vc++ dll with just one function exported in def file. The code is very simple but would still post here to give a content and make sure there's no problem there.

```
//also tried __declspec(dllexport) double sumCPP(double a, double b) without .def file
double __stdcall sumCPP(double a, double b)
{
    return a + b;
}

'VBA
Public Declare PtrSafe Function sumCpp Lib "C:\MyTestProject\x64\Debug\DllTest.dll" (ByVal a As Double, ByVal b As Double) As Double
```

But a call from VBA results Run-time error '48': File not found: C:\MyTestProject\x64\Debug\DllTest.dll.

The source code of a more complicated dll project can be built to exe that runs fine, but whose dll prompted this original failure calling dll problem. Any suggestion where to look at? I've tried depends.exe with many supposedly false alarms and dumpbin /dependents but not clear how to use the result. I wonder if this is related to some vs2015 redistributable not in system PATH. I don't see any there but haven't tried to add them yet, as there seem to be too many.

Is there any other option to delegate heavy computation and TCP/IP socket besides using vc++ dll? I don't know but can consider C#, while python would be preferred. Since those dll functions are intended to be called many times in VBA, a system call to vc++ exe doesn't seem to be efficient.

Great thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Test the dll on the develop machine 2. Use release mode, because the function signature is different  3.Check this: Excel is x64 and dll is x86? or Excel is x86 and dll is x64?

Answer (score 0):

Since the machine is new so I reset it removing all data. Then I installed Office 2016 64bit and VS Community 2015 from scratch and built the 64bit dll again. This time the error is Run-time error '453' Can't find DLL entry point. Can't find any obvious missing dependent dll by either dumpbin.exe /dependents or depends.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Try change build configuration from "Debug" to "Release"

Comment: And also make sure that you have vsruntime140.dll in SysWow64 folder